# How to make UITableView scrollable

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

When I want to scroll UITableView, it reverts to its initial state.
I recorded a video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lp0NmNnv7bE
I don't know in which part of code I can fix it, so if you know, told me, and I'll write my code.

My code is here: http://github.com/serg1991/diplom_newbase/blob/master/diplom/BiletChildViewController.m
What I have to fix?

Comment: did you set contentsize of scrollview?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/CreatingBasicScrollViews/CreatingBasicScrollViews.html

Comment: I have this method in code: - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    CGRect frame = self.tableView.frame;
    frame.size = self.tableView.contentSize;
    self.tableView.frame = frame;
}

Comment: Why do you set table view frame equal to it's content size? See me answer below, there i described your problem

Answer (score 2):

UITableView scrolls back because it's content size is equal to it's frame (or near to it). If you want to scroll it without returning you need add more cells: table view content size will be large then it's frame. Another case: you change table view content size manually, if it's true then you shouldn't do it in usual case.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to change the content size of a UITableView manually , the content size will be adjusted automatically according to the total number of rows and the height of each row.

So, first need to remove the content size setting from the code.

Then,

1. Confirm, no any other views overlapped the tableview.
2. Confirm, You are calling the 'reloadData' after a dynamic height change of cell.
3. Try reducing tableview height and see whether you are able to scroll and position all the the cells.
4. There is a default bounce property to all scroll views , that you can switch it off from the property view.

Comment: I tried to remove contentSize setting and reduce tableview height. Now it scrolls, but tableview height is less than content size :(

Comment: Now table view height is actually how I set in xib file

Comment: "but tableview height is less than content size :(" , yes that is correct. If the table view height is less than content size then only we can scroll. If both are same what is the requirement of scrolling ?

Comment: english isn't my native language, so maybe I can't describe my problem. First, if content size is more than table view height, we have to scroll it. Second, if content size is less than table view height, table view height must be reduce, so content size and table size height must be equal. I don't know how do it.